# Laravel 5 Auth - How to output the status message after email sent from password reset page

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, passwords, reset

How to output the status message after password reset button is click in built in auth in laravel 5.1 on your view?

Answer (score 11):

The code is in Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords

at function postReset.

```
public function postReset(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only(
            'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );

        $response = Password::reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
            $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
        });

        switch ($response) {
            case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
                return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('status', trans($response));

            default:
                return redirect()->back()
                            ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                            ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
        }
    }
```

Check the case Password:PASSWORD_RESET: the status is the variable responsible for the message. and the value of this variable is

> "We have e-mailed your password reset link!"

use the code below to output the status message above

```
{{ Session::get('status') }}
```

or you can use

```
{{ Session::has('status') }}
```

and it will return you a value of 1.

To change the value of the status message just go to

> /resources/lang/en/passwords.php

below is the code of the passwords.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reminder Language Lines
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The following language lines are the default lines which match reasons
    | that are given by the password broker for a password update attempt
    | has failed, such as for an invalid token or invalid new password.
    |
    */

    'password' => 'Passwords must be at least six characters and match the confirmation.',
    'reset' => 'Your password has been reset!',
    'sent' => 'We have e-mailed your password reset link!',
    'token' => 'This password reset token is invalid.',
    'user' => "We can't find a user with that e-mail address.",

];
```

Hope this helps you.